# Calling XSLT variable in CSS import

Tags: xslt

I tried calling CSS import but cannot evaluate XSLT variable. Is there any other way of doing this?

```
  <xsl:template match="/" priority="1">

    <xsl:variable name="RecipeId" select="page/abc/a'" />
    <xsl:variable name="CampaignId" select="page/abc/a" />

    @import "lander_umetrix_264.css?ucid={$CampaignId}&#38;urid={$RecipeId}";
    <!--@import "lander.css";-->

    @import "nav_umetrix_264.css?ucid={$CampaignId}&#38;urid={$RecipeId}";


    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions in curly brackets are only expanded inside [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

Instead of `{$CampaignId}`, you can use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$CampaignId"/>
```